# Is there a way to use the MqttAndroidClient in with Android 14?

Tags: android, kotlin, mqtt, paho

Both HiveMQ and Paho libraries make use of `AlarmPingSender`. However, this library is not updated yet making it impossible (I think?) to use MQTT with Android 14. Anyone that can help me?

I tried to change my SDK versions or to make an own custom `PingSender` implementation, but as a student I found this rather hard. I really don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been using hivemq on Android 14 for a few months but have not upgraded my project to 14. That said there are a couple forks of paho that claim to support 14 you may look at (this one for example https://github.com/mayzs/paho.mqtt.android)
The main repo for paho on Android is dead unfortunately.